# Can I include component supplier url in Altium Designer BOM file?

Tags: altium, bom

I'm new to Altium Designer and experimenting with a small pcb. Now that I've finished it I was considering ordering it at Seeed Studio and was curious about the posibilities to have it assemblied. I noticed they wanted links to the supplier pages of each component.

I suspect there must be a way to automatically include these links in the generated BOM file, since I've added all components through the Manufacturer Part Search. Yet I can't find a way how to do that.

Comment: Create a new user_field for all components.

Comment: So, I then still would have to add them there manually? That's too bad then. But on the other hand, the BOM already contains supplier, SPN and MPN. Perhaps that's enough for most pcb companies.

Comment: Try [The celestial library](https://altiumlibrary.com/) - it has a full data base including supplier part links. Open Source & free.